# 3 phase heating control of hot water

Tags: three-phase

I am looking for some help on a system which I have here. There is a temperature probe in a tank which is monitoring the temp of a liquid and the controller output is switching a 3 phase contactor on and off when the temp of the liquid drops below the setpoint and then switches the contactor back off when the setpoint is reached again. The problem is now that over the weekend the contactor welded closed and kept heating the liquid which had to be dumped. There is an over temp alarm relay output on the controller which was not connected to the circuit therefore no failsafe. I need to configure this now so that the contactor coil switches on and off as normal through the relay output of the controller for when it drops below setpoint and then switch off when setpoint is reached. But i also must now get the over temp alarm into the circuit to switch the contactor off as well. I am a little confused as to how to go about this as in should i install a safety contactor so that if contacts weld shut no power will flow, should I put in a safety relay, or change the type of temp controller with different outputs instead of relay outputs. Or maybe a logic module of some sort? The temp controller in question is an Omron E5CSV

Comment: You need to investigate why the contactor failed and understand why. That knowledge will govern how you move forward.

Comment: Looks like one of the terminals burnt out on the 3rd phase

Comment: But why did they burn out and, one set of contacts burning doesn't cause a current to flow.

Comment: I'm not sure i think there may have been issues with inrush current but the first and second phase had 400v between them and the third only had 230 between 1 and 2

Comment: I'm not going to pursue this because it seems I'm probably wasting my time.

Comment: For other readers: The same question is also active on the All About Circuits forum [here](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/temperature-control-of-3-phase-heaters.174424/), so for anyone looking to avoid duplicating effort, it's possible that updates / solutions etc. might appear there.

Comment: why are you wasting your time Andy?

Answer (score 2):

> But i also must now get the over temp alarm into the circuit to switch the contactor off as well.

I think you can see the problem with this. If the contactor contacts have welded then it doesn't matter what protection you add to the coil - the contacts will remain welded.

The standard course of action is to use the over-temperature trip and a separate contactor with its contacts wired in series with the normal one. The safety contactor will see very few cycles in normal operation so the contacts are unlikely to weld.

Comment: Not really sure i understand what you mean on this

Comment: In case of welding contacts, disconnecting contactor 's coil will not help. You just need to find more reliable contactor, properly rated for your load. And may add sound alarm , connected to auxiliary alarm output, may be just buzzer

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

A three phase immersion heater generally comprises three, star-connected single phase heaters.

It is standard practice to use heaters equipped with a back-up 'Invar/Brass Stem Thermostat' having its 'NC' contact wired in series with the heater.

[image]

The back-up thermostat is set for a slightly higher temperature than that set in the temperature controller to prevent liquid overheating, should the temperature controller fail or contactor contacts weld.